# FLEX :: Embed DateField Font

Tags: css, apache-flex, fonts, thin-client

**TLDR;**

How do you embed a font in flex for a DateField?

**Question:**

I have a Flex program which is using a `<mx:DateField>`. The environment it was created for has been switched over to using thin clients.

As a result, I now have to embed all the fonts within the application, otherwise all characters are replaced with ⛞ *(Note: I couldn't find the exact symbol, but its a null character)*.

This is what the calendar looks like **without** the embed code **outside** of a thin client.

[image: Before embedded font]

**Applciation.mxml**

```
@font-face{
    src: url("/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf");
    fontFamily: Arial;
    embedAsCFF:true; 
}
```

This **fixes** every other font. Except the `<mx:DateField>`.

[image: After font is embedded]

This occurs no matter what font is embedded, even when **outside** the thin client.

So I'm slightly lost on how to fix this issue. The fonts have to be embedded in order for the calendar to become readable, but this breaks the calendar.

Cheers and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The implications of this appear when you try to use MX controls with a font that was embedded with FTE support. In those cases, the text does not appear." - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS0FA8AEDB-C69F-4f19-ADA5-AA5757217624.html

i.e.

```
 @font-face{
    src: url("/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf");
    fontFamily: Arial;
    embedAsCFF:true; 
}
```

Needed to be:

```
 @font-face{
    src: url("/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf");
    fontFamily: Arial;
    embedAsCFF:false; 
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

create custom compo and embed your font with embedAsCFF false to it runtime
help is here
http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/03/01/download-custom-flex-3-datechooser-2/